# How to fix Rails No route matches [POST] or [OPTION] for the root URL "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Our logs are filling up with lots of `rails No route matches [POST] "/"` and `rails No route matches [OPTIONS] "/"` errors, specifically for our root path.

In our `routes.rb` we have a catch all at the end;

```rb
match '*url' => 'errors#not_found', via: :all
```

This works for e.g. `POST /blah` or `OPTIONS /foo` but doesn't appear to catch `POST /`.

In this specific app which is API only, we even tell our root path to 404, with;

```rb
root 'errors#not_found'
```

Which works for `GET /`.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new route for the root path that matches all methods:

```rb
  match '/' => 'errors#not_found', via: :all
```

Comment: Thanks @David, happy to add this, but is that not what the `*` should be doing in my original catch all?

Comment: I see this as an alternative `root` definition. I bumped into the same problem earlier, and though I didn't go through the internals, defining the root like this solved it.